# Creating instances of Ember models not attached to a store

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-components

I'm using Ember 2.0 with ember-data 2.0.

In Rails it's very common to model forms and components using real instances of models. For a `posts/new` form you would pass in a `Post.new` and use that inside the `form.html.erb` template.

In Ember that is made difficult because calling `new Post` creates a broken model. Instead you're encouraged to use stores, and with that use `this.store.createRecord('post');`.

This is fine, but not when building isolated components. For example a form where the user can add multiple models, say a category creator. In my head the structure would be something as follows:

`category-form/template.hbs`

```
<button {{action 'addCategory'}}>Add category</button>
{{#each categories as |category|}}
    {{input value=category.name}}
{{/each}}
<button {{action 'save'}}>Save</button>
```

Then the component.js would be something like:

`category-form/component.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Category from 'app/category/model';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    categories: [],

    actions: {
        addCategory() {
            // THIS DOES NOT WORK
            this.get("categories").pushObject(new Category);
        },

        save() {
            this.sendAction("saveCategories", this.get("categories"));
        }
    }
});
```

The example above does work, but would instead require `this.store.createRecord`. But as far as I know the component does not have access to the store. This is sane because that would be the component messing with a global state. Also when using `createRecord` you end up with lots of residual models in the store if the user navigates away without saving the model.

I want the `category-form` component in this example to be completely isolated from the rest of the global state.

My question is, how would this be handled correctly using ember logic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you wrote is correct and it is considered as a good pattern - your components work without store and some parent of them (preferably route, but may be controller) is handling persisting these data to API.

In your example you do not have to use `store` in component at all. You can create some `Ember.Object` instances on each `addCategory` action execution which will be send to your parent. This parent would obtain the array of `Ember.Object`, copy the attributes that you want to use to instances of models and save them.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    categories: [],

    actions: {
        addCategory() {
            this.get("categories").pushObject(Ember.Object.create({
                name: ''
            });
        },

        save() {
            this.sendAction("saveCategories", this.get("categories"));
        }
    }
});
```

And in your route you can do as follows:

```
actions: {
  saveCategories(categories) {
    let categoryRecords = categories.map((item) => {
      return this.store.createRecord('category', { name: item.get('name') });
    });
  }
}
```

On the other hand, if you would need some features of Ember Data models as relationships, you can actually send the action `addCategory` up to the route/controller, create the model and pass down as binding to that component:

```
{{category-form categories=categories saveCategories="saveCategories" addCategory="addCategory}}
```

And then in your route/controller:

```
   categories: [], 
   actions: {
      addCategory() {
        this.get('categories').pushObject(this.store.createRecord('category'));
      },
      saveCategories() {
        this.get('categories')... // do what you want with them
      }
    }
```

Comment: That sounds logical, but I'm wondering with the latter approach, if for example I would have a pretty complex model (let's imagine that the Category model has many relationships), and I make a `category-form` that bubbles up all actions to the route or controller, I would essentially be duplicating the logic in both the edit route, and the create route.

Comment: ... How would you deal with this? Create a temporary DTO for example?

Comment: I don't think that you would duplicate any logic. In your component, even if you would have couple of actions, all of them would be just sending them up. All the logic would be in one place - the route or the controller. And if two routes or controller share the same logic, it's a perfect place to use Ember.Mixin and extract that logic to a mixin. And what is temporary DTO?

Comment: A DTO is just a Java-ism, it's a class with all the properties and fields but no logic attached, that you can pass around in the system. Data Transfer Object. But I'll try out the mixin approach, it seemed pretty nice! Thanks so much